# What is the difference between linux and windows from web application testing point of view

Tags: manual-testing, functional, performance-testing

What is the difference between Linux and Windows from a web application testing point of view?

Comment: Hi Iqra, your question is quite broad in a way that we can't give you a definitive answer. This means your question risks being closed, unless you're able to expand on the issue and ask for something more specific?

Comment: Hi, I want to ask testing perspective to test an application on Linux and how it is different from Windows. Thanks

Comment: It might be very different, or same, depending on what you are testing.

Answer (score 1):

From the testing point of view tester's needs to consider the following:

- Make sure Javascript gets loads properly in both OS versions
- Design issues will occur make sure the CSS gets loaded properly when testing in a application in Windows and linux
- Some of the Ajax calls may not work in linux but will work on windows or viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is different.

You're trying to test the same web app on two different systems and that'll affect everything - functional, non-functional, performance, penetration tests, etc.

Even the browser you're using will be different between the two operating systems, so you're effectively testing two different web apps.

In my experience, a large portion of your test cases will remain the same between the two systems (because the functionality will be very similar) but you'll have have to run them twice. Once on Linux, and again one Windows.

Comment: can you elaborate more about functional, non-functional, performance, and penetration tests ?